# How to get data from one page to other page reactjs Basic of two click events

Tags: reactjs

```
import somePdf from '../file/somePdf.pdf';
import somePdf2 from '../file/somePdf2.pdf';


callPdf = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };


 <NavLink
    to="/"
    onClick={this.callPdf}
  >
    pdf1
  </NavLink>

  <a href="#" onClick={this.callPdf}>
    pdf2
</a>

{this.state.isOpen ? (
  <PdfReader
    closePopup={this.callPdf}
    url={somePdf}
  />
) : null}
</div>

{this.state.isOpen ? (
<PdfReader 
closePopup={this.callPdf} 
url={somePdf2}/>
) : null}

//Other component


<PDFReader  url={this.props.url}/> // Here I'm getting only one data
```

Its only accepting only somePdf not allow to get chance somePdf2 I didn't get this one how to fix it please guide thanks a ton in advance

Expecting two click does provide two files seperately how this make works please guide

Comment: Is <PdfReader /> component a Dialog component or just downloading ? if it's a dialog then comment this line (closePopup={this.callPdf} ) from first PdfReader or that's just downloading then put both PdfReader inside one of this.state.isOpen checking.

Comment: This is not very complete code, can you provide complete component code of the component you're struggling with, or share a codesandbox that reproduces the issue? On the surface it seems `PDFReader` only displays a single pdf url so on that last line it'll only display one specified by `props.url`.